# Draw a random variable from a list?

Tags: php, arrays, list, variables, random

So I'm making this RPG game in PHP as a way to familiarize myself in the language more. I've built a fairly good system so far. Right now I'm working on the shop. I've made it so it selects a certain amount of goods in each category (weapons, armor, etc.) depending on the size of the city (village, town, city, etc.) by using arrays to store the variables. That's worked awesome.

What I now want to do is make a list of each item I want the shop to potentially sell, then randomly pick one of those items for each of the slots the store will sell. For example, at the smallest city size, the shop sells two weapons. It will randomly pick two weapons from the weapon list to show the player. I've been using includes as an easy way to store "lists" like this, so all I really need to do is find a way for the game to randomly pick x amount of items from a list provided by an include and store it in a variable in an array.

Bonus points if you're able to make it so randomly picking the items is never the same item. (like if we're picking two items and the items were "Iron Sword", "Steel Sword" and "Dragon Sword" or something, it never will say "Iron Sword" and "Iron Sword")

Here's my code excerpts so far.

Decide how many items to show. (Where the "Iron Sword"; is shown is where the variables are going to be stored. These were dummy items thrown in.)

```
$Weapons = 2 * $citysize;
$Armor = 2 * $citysize;
$Misc = $citysize;

include 'weapons.php';

if ($Weapons == 2){
    $_SESSION['ShopWeapons'][0] = "Iron Sword";
    $_SESSION['ShopWeapons'][1] = "Everwood Staff";
} elseif ($Weapons == 4){
    $_SESSION['ShopWeapons'][0] = "Iron Sword";
    $_SESSION['ShopWeapons'][1] = "Everwood Staff";
    $_SESSION['ShopWeapons'][2] = "Steel Sword";
    $_SESSION['ShopWeapons'][3] = "Balsa Wand";
} elseif ($Weapons == 6){
    $_SESSION['ShopWeapons'][0] = "Iron Sword";
    $_SESSION['ShopWeapons'][1] = "Everwood Staff";
    $_SESSION['ShopWeapons'][2] = "Steel Sword";
    $_SESSION['ShopWeapons'][3] = "Balsa Wand";
    $_SESSION['ShopWeapons'][4] = "Steel Dagger";
    $_SESSION['ShopWeapons'][5] = "Balsa Bow";
}
```

Show the items in the shop

```
echo $_SESSION['ShopWeapons'][0] . "<br>";
echo $_SESSION['ShopWeapons'][1] . "<br>";

if(($_SESSION["citysize"] == "town") || ($_SESSION["citysize"] == "city")){
    echo $_SESSION['ShopWeapons'][2] . "<br>";
    echo $_SESSION['ShopWeapons'][3] . "<br>";
}

if($_SESSION["citysize"] == "city"){
    echo $_SESSION['ShopWeapons'][4] . "<br>";
    echo $_SESSION['ShopWeapons'][5] . "<br>";
}
```

Thank you a million times in advance

Comment: `$indexes = array_rand($array, $items_amount)`

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy. When you select a random item from the weapons array before displaying it remove it from the array. This way when you go to pick another random weapon it cannot be a choice.

```
while NumberItems < MaxItems
    weapon = NextWeapon()
    RemoveWeapon( weapon )
    AddWeaponToStore( weapon )
    NumberItems++

DisplayStoreHtml()
```

Comment: `weapon = NextWeapon()` <- how is that random? :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`shuffle`](http://php.net/shuffle) to randomize array order?

Comment: Hmm ... this idea would work marvelously, however, if the array is stored in a session, would that still work?

Comment: Sure, what difference does it make? `shuffle($_SESSION['ShopWeapons'])`